# Woocommerce get parent's description from variation product

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to get the descritpiton of the parent product from a series of variation.

I tried this way

```
$args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
            'suppress_filters' => false,
            'orderby'       => 'title',
            'order'         => 'DESC'       );
$products = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ( $products as $productId ) {
                $product = wc_get_product( $productId );    
                $parent = $product->get_parent_data();
    ....
```

where product is my variation. But in parent data i haven't a description.
Any suggestions on how can I get the description?

Comment: `$products` contain variations?

Comment: yes. ```$args = array(
   'numberposts'  => -1,
   'post_type'    => 'product_variation',
   'suppress_filters' => false,
   'orderby'  => 'title',
   'order'         => 'DESC'
  );  
  $products = get_posts( $args ); ```

Comment: Please add the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_parent_id` to get the parent product id. Try the below code.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'      => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'product_variation',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'order'            => 'DESC'       
);

$products = get_posts( $args ); 

$productsIds = array(); // store product id for avoid duplication.

foreach ( $products as $variation_id ) {
    
    $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
    $product   = wc_get_product( $variation->get_parent_id() );

    if( !in_array( $product->get_id(), $productsIds ) && $product ){
        $productsIds[]             = $product->get_id();
        $product_details           = $product->get_data();
        $product_full_description  = $product_details['description'];
        $product_short_description = $product_details['short_description'];
    }

}
```

Comment: worked in this way: `if( !in_array( $product->get_id(), $productsIds ) &&  product )`